# Show all categories pages in WordPress sitemap?

Tags: sitemap

Good day, dear specialists. There is such a code

```
$categoriesForSitemap = get_categories(array(
 'hide_empty' => 1, 
 'depth' => 0, 
 'hierarchical' => false
 ));
foreach($categoriesForSitemap as $category) {
    $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
    $sitemap .= '<url>' . '<loc>' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '</loc>' . '<priority>1</priority>' . '<lastmod></lastmod>' . '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' . '</url>';
}
```

How can I enable adding all category pages in it? Those.

```
category-name/page/2/ 
category-name/page/3/
.....
```

and so on.

I generate a local cache in xampp and then upload it to the hosting. And there is an extreme lack of links to categories pagination.
Plase help me.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I generate a local cache in xampp and then upload it to the hosting. And there is an extreme lack of links to categories pagination.